# unit tests observable values comes in separate tick

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, observable

I want to simulate in my tests that values from the observable are coming in a sequence, one at a time (so sometimes I want to use setTimeout(,0) to achive this) and I can test this and at the end I want to test that observable subscription inside my test was entered (because sometimes test is success because it didn't entered the subscribed handler and no expectation was executed).

In order to understand how to deal with observables during unit tests I try the following.

I have a function that returns an observable. This is just a mock function. (Normally, the values comes from another observable which gets the values from  from http.)

```
export function getObs(): Observable<string[]> {
  let obs = Observable.create( (observer: Observer<string[]>) => {
    observer.next([]);
    observer.next(["x1", "x2"]);
    observer.complete();
  });

  return obs;
}


describe( "aa ", () => {

  fit("aa", async(() => {

    let counter = 0;
    getObs().subscribe(
      (res:string[])=> {
        counter++;
        console.debug("---- iter " + counter + " res:" +res);
        if( counter === 1)
          expect(res.length).toBe(0);
        if( counter === 2)
          expect(res.length).toBe(2);
      },
      () => { console.debug("---  completed " + counter); }
    );

    console.debug("counter:"+counter);
    expect(counter).toBe(2);
    setTimeout(()=> expect(counter).toBe(2),0 );
  }))

});
```

I expect that two values to be are emitted by the observables and after that it completes.
The output is the following:

    `DEBUG: '---- iter: 1 res:'
    DEBUG: '---- iter: 2 res:x1,x2'
    DEBUG: 'counter:2'`

There are several issues here and even more things I don't understand.

- completed callback is never called .
- counter is 2 immediately after subscribe block. I was expecting that only inside setTimeout() to see counter 2. So this raise the question: how is this code executed ? In which sequence ?
- with or without `async` - the behavior is the same. (Again, the previous question gain in importantance). Why ?

I want to master in unit tests the sequence of values that comes from an observable AND to test at the end that subscribed handler was called.
The sequence of values should come ideally in different ticks, to simulate http responses, so to be asynchronous.

In this first test variant I was `complete`-ing the observable under test (but still my complete handler in test was not called) and observable values comes in the same tick.

Now here is **another variant**: using subject - but here I don't know to `complete` the sequence and I send values in different ticks.

```
 export function getObs2(): Observable<string[]> {
  const subject = new ReplaySubject<string[]>(1);

  subject.next([]);
//  subject.next(["x1", "x2"]);
  setTimeout( () => subject.next(["x1", "x2"]), 0 );

  return subject.asObservable();
}

  fit("b", async(() => {

    let counter = 0;
    getObs2().subscribe(
      (res:string[])=> {
        counter++;
        console.debug("---- iter: " + counter + " res:" +res);
        if( counter === 1)
          expect(res.length).toBe(0);
        if( counter === 2)
          expect(res.length).toBe(2);
      },
      () => { console.debug("---  completed " + counter); }
    );

    console.debug("counter:"+counter);
//    expect(counter).toBe(2); <---- this fails as counter is 1 here
    setTimeout(()=> expect(counter).toBe(20),0 ); // just to be print an error with the value of counter, to be sure that it reach here.
  }))
```

Result is:

    `DEBUG: '---- iter: 1 res:'
    DEBUG: 'counter:1'
    DEBUG: '---- iter: 2 res:x1,x2'
[1]     Expected 2 to be 20.`

Now in `getObs2()` I emit two values - but second value I emit in next tick (I use setTimeout) because otherwise the `getObs2().subscribe` is entered only once  not two times (why ?). So I emit the values in separate ticks and this way the subscribe handler is called twice.
Now the counter is 1 - executed in first tick I guess- and I need to expect the counter to be 2 in the next tick.
The complete handler is not called.

What is happening if this test is not `async` ? I remove the `async` and ...

    `DEBUG: '---- iter: 1 res:'
    DEBUG: 'counter:1'
    DEBUG: '---- iter: 2 res:x1,x2'`

which means that last line is not executed  ? (should see the error)

```
setTimeout(()=> expect(counter).toBe(20),0 );
```

but `setTimeout()` inside `getObs2()` is executed ....

Can someone explain me what is going on ? 
I clearly don't get something in working with unit tests sync/async & observables & setTimeout .... This combination is quite difficult...

Ideally I want:

- observable values served in different ticks (simulated from a MockBackend that uses also setTimeout(,0) to send response)
- specific tests during each tick
- specific tests at the end (perhaps when observable completes ? - but it never completes in unit tests - why ?)
- understand what I can do in sync test from above and what in async tests.
  In the first test variant the behavior is the same in both sync/async strategy. The second test: in sync case - it can't check the counter in a next tick  but it can emit an observable value in the next tick - this is strange.